# Indefinite Integration of real valued function

Tags: integration, approximate-integration

Why  $\int e^{-x^2} dx$ cannot be expressed in a closed form? Definite integration of this function is possible however I could not understand why indefinite Integration is not possible.

Comment: What do wupu mean when you say that “Definite integration of this function is possible”? How do you do that?

Comment: It is not that it is impossible, actually the indefinite integral exists, but cannot be expressed in terms of "elementary" (don't know the precise term) functions.

Comment: There are complicated algorithms which allow us to tell if a certain function has an antiderivative expressible in terms of elementary functions. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for details (Risch algorithm). It is well known that $e^{-x^2}$ isn't one of those functions.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to integrate $\int e^{-x^2}\,dx$ is to use the infinite series representation for $e^{-x^2}$. But the answer is going to be another infinite series.

Comment: Please look a glance on this link "http://math.hunter.cuny.edu/ksda/papers/rick_09_02.pdf" Page No. 20 (Corollary 4.4), you can find your answer.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).